# Oracle proxy authentication: Rollback of whole transaction

Tags: jpa, oracle11g, eclipselink, jta

Using Glassfish 4.1, Eclipselink 2.5.1, Oracle 11g.

We're having a problem rolling back changes when persisting a one-to-many (parent-children) relationship using **Oracle proxy authentication**. If any exception is thrown when persisting one of the children, the parent will still be persisted to the DB (not rolled back as expected). We save to DB from a stateless EJB with a container-managed JTA entitymanager with:

```
entitymanager.persist(parent);
```

`cascade = CascadeType.ALL` is used on the relationship on the parent side.

Our persistence.xml contains `<persistence-unit name="admin_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">` and the problem at hand is the only one we have in the persistence layer (so far, everything else is working fine).

The parent entity is something like:

```
public class KornstoranalyseStd implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "KORNSTORANALYSE_STD_ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer kornstoranalyseStdId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "kornstoranalyseStd", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy("maskestoerrelse DESC")
    private Collection<KornstoranalyseStdSigte> kornstoranalyseStdSigteCollection;
}
```

And the child entity is:

```
public class KornstoranalyseStdSigte implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "KORNSTORANALYSE_STD_SIGTE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer kornstoranalyseStdSigteId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "MASKESTOERRELSE", nullable = false, precision = 12, scale = 8)
    private BigDecimal maskestoerrelse;

    @JoinColumn(name = "KORNSTORANALYSE_STD_ID", referencedColumnName = "KORNSTORANALYSE_STD_ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private KornstoranalyseStd kornstoranalyseStd;
}
```

The following code is for testing only:

```
    KornstoranalyseStd parent = new KornstoranalyseStd();
    parent.setKornstoranalyseStdId(1);
    List<KornstoranalyseStdSigte> children = new ArrayList<>();
    KornstoranalyseStdSigte child = new KornstoranalyseStdSigte();
    child.setKornstoranalyseStdSigteId(1);
    child.setMaskestoerrelse(new BigDecimal(11));
    child.setKornstoranalyseStd(parent);
    children.add(child);
    parent.setKornstoranalyseStdSigteCollection(children);
    getEjbFacade().create(parent);
```

This is the STSB:

```
@Stateless
public class KornstoranalyseStdFacade {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "admin_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public void create(KornstoranalyseStd entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    }
}
```

In all calls through the EJB, we proxy the entitymanager with

```
        getEntityManager().setProperty("eclipselink.oracle.proxy-type", 1);
        getEntityManager().setProperty("PROXY_USER_NAME", loginBean.getUsername());
        getEntityManager().setProperty("PROXY_USER_PASSWORD", loginBean.getPassword());
        getEntityManager().setProperty("eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.mode", "Always");
        getEntityManager().setProperty("eclipselink.jdbc.exclusive-connection.is-lazy", "true");
```

The above lines are in an `@AroundInvoke-method`, and will therefore be run no matter what EJB-method is accessed.

The problem is only present when proxying, not if we omit that part. It seems the problem is related to the jdbc-connections being autocommitted. We've tried all kinds of parameters in the Glassfish Connection pool; relaxAutoCommit=true, AutoCommit=false etc., but nothing has changed anything.

How can we ensure, that the parent is also rolled back, when persisting a child fails?

Comment: You haven't shown the transaction demarcation, the datasource definition or the exception itself, so we can't see what the problem is.  My guess is that you haven't setup a JTA datasource in glassfish, so that EclipseLink is writing through a connection outside of the transaction, causing each statement to be auto-commited individually.

Comment: Thanks very much Chris - you're right, I omitted much for brevity. The demarcation is given by using CMT in the STSB, is'nt it? Sorry I did'nt state explicitely. Is anything special needed for a JTA datasource in GF (we have a "standard" datasource/connection pool defined)? However, it seems the problem was with Oracle proxy authentification, which was another thing I omitted for simplicity. It seems to result in a connection outside of the transaction, as you say. Will delete question if confirmed. Thanks for comment again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick solution seems to be:

- End the ejb-method with `em.flush();`

That'll make the parent roll back too - don't ask me why.

Note that the exception thrown when persisting a child entity fails will be different (e.getCause() will be different, in case you show to the enduser, but it will still be wrapped in an EJBException).

Another solution is:

- Use RESOURCE_LOCAL and non-jta-data-source as written in other answer. You'll have to inject the EntityManagerFactory in the EJB and do the transaction handling yourself.

I didn't find a way to configure me out of it.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when using  entitymanager with datsource defined in application server. for solving the problem i did this:

1- i set transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" in persistence.xml and for defining persistence-unit

2- I used non-jta-data-source property with value of myDatasourceName

i realized that root of exception is jta!

Comment: Are you using oracle proxy authentication too, @Abbas?